# How can I pull a docker image in a Kubernetes cluster from a private registry behind a ssh connection

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ssh

I’m trying to deploy a docker image on a kubernetes cluster. This cluster is on a server accessible via a ssh connection.

Here is the part of the .yaml I use to pull the image :

```
spec :
  containers :
  - name : my_image_name
    image : my_private_registry/my_image
```

my_image is stored in a private registry in another server accessible via a ssh connection (with a proxyjump).

I know how to pull an image from a private registry that is on the same server that the kubernetes cluster. But when it is on another server, I don’t. I'm sure that it is possible to configure kubernetes to make it use the ssh connection, but I didn't find ressources helping me to do that. The others private registry are accessible just by a "docker login" command ?

I’ve found a beginning of solution sending the image using a package named « docker_over_ssh », but it was not really appropriate. I’ve found a solution by pushing the image on dockerhub, but I’m sure that we can do better …

Thank you for your help. I’m sure that it is not complicated, but I’m quite new in kubernetes and docker.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite important to understand, that the docker daemon does not run inside kubernetes. So whatever you provide through kubernetes objects (pods, services...) is usually not accessible from outside.

You could provide a mirror registry for your cluster, so that it is accessible in the usual way.
Another option would be to use ssh port forwarding, if the ssh proxy allows that and use the forwarding host as registry.

Comment: I was able to push the image to the kube server (with the docker-over-ssh package). But there, I didn't success to make it seen by the kubernetes cluster : I tried to push it in a local registry, but the k8s cluster still can't see it. About the ssh port forwarding, I can do that, but I don't know how to configure kubernetes that way.

Comment: Where/how do you operate the local registry?

Comment: I created the local registry on the server where k8s is deployed, using this tutorial : https://docs.docker.com/registry/. But when I try to pull the image via the .yaml, I've got a ErrImagePull error.

Comment: If you run the registry on a single server and it is the same server your whole cluster is running on (without additional VMs) you need to use localhost:5000 as registry URL

Comment: I think that it is the problem : the image is deployed on working nodes that are running on additional VMs. So, the localhost:5000 doesn't work. Thank's for your help. I will try to do it differently.

Comment: Then just use the hostname and port which can be used to access the registry, just be sure not to use kubernetes concepts, like service names, which are only available in the cluster. You might want to consider a TLS setup since insecure registries are usually only support on localhost.